# placing ng-table pagination after <div id="test1">

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, ngtable

I have created an angularjs application using ng-table with customized pagination template. The application is working fine but the issue is that I want the pagination to be appeared after a `<div id="test1">`.

My code is as given below, can anyone please tell me some solution for this

**[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56kwnyo1/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-app="main" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <table class="table" ng-table="tableParams" template-pagination="custom/pager" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th sortable="'name'">NUMBER</th>
                <th sortable="'age'">STATUS</th>
                <th sortable="'role'">LOB</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="user in $data| filter:searchPolicies">
                <td><span ng-bind="user.name"></span>

                </td>
                <td><span ng-bind="user.age"></span>

                </td>
                <td><span ng-bind="user.role"></span>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="test1">some data</div>
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="custom/pager">
<div class="ng-cloak ng-table-pager" ng-if="params.data.length">
    <div ng-if="params.settings().counts.length"
        class="ng-table-counts btn-group pull-right">
        <button ng-repeat="count in params.settings().counts" type="button"
            ng-class="{'active':params.count()==count}"
            ng-click="params.count(count)" class="btn btn-default">
            <span ng-bind="count"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <ul ng-if="pages.length" class="pagination ng-table-pagination">
        <li ng-class="{'disabled': !page.active && !page.current, 'active': page.current}" ng-repeat="page in pages" ng-switch="page.type">
            <a ng-switch-when="prev" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">Prev</a>
            <a ng-switch-when="first" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">
                <span ng-bind="page.number"></span>
            </a> 
            <a ng-switch-when="page" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">
                <span ng-bind="page.number"></span>
            </a> 
            <a ng-switch-when="more" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">&#8230;</a> 
            <a ng-switch-when="last" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">
                <span ng-bind="page.number"></span>
            </a> 
            <a ng-switch-when="next" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">Next</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
    </script>
</div>
```

**script**

```
 $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,
        count: 5, // count per page
        sorting: {
            name: "asc"
        }
    }, {
        counts: [],
        getData: function ($defer, params) {
            var orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) : data;
            params.total(data.length);
            $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the div you want between the table and pagination isn't too large, you could just add it to the beginning of the pagination script.

i.e.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="custom/pager">
    <div id="test1">some data</div>
    <div class="ng-cloak ng-table-pager" ng-if="params.data.length">
        <div ng-if="params.settings().counts.length"
            class="ng-table-counts btn-group pull-right">
            <button ng-repeat="count in params.settings().counts" type="button"
                ng-class="{'active':params.count()==count}"
                ng-click="params.count(count)" class="btn btn-default">
                <span ng-bind="count"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <ul ng-if="pages.length" class="pagination ng-table-pagination">
            <li ng-class="{'disabled': !page.active && !page.current, 'active': page.current}" ng-repeat="page in pages" ng-switch="page.type">
                <a ng-switch-when="prev" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">Prev</a>
                <a ng-switch-when="first" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">
                    <span ng-bind="page.number"></span>
                </a> 
                <a ng-switch-when="page" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">
                    <span ng-bind="page.number"></span>
                </a> 
                <a ng-switch-when="more" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">&#8230;</a> 
                <a ng-switch-when="last" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">
                    <span ng-bind="page.number"></span>
                </a> 
                <a ng-switch-when="next" ng-click="params.page(page.number)" href="">Next</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

[**Updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/56kwnyo1/1/)